# What is the right way to make a public property

Tags: php, yii

For a assignment I need to make a public property on a class.

So I did this :

```
<?php

class MessageController extends Controller
{
    public $defaultAction  =  "hello" ;

    var $theTime = date ( "D M j G:i:s T Y");

    public function actionHello()
    {
            this->render('hello');

    }
```

but now I see a blank screen.

What did I do wrong ?

Roelof

Edit 1: I use the Yii platform.

Edit 2:  Where can I find info how I can make this class property the right way ?

Comment: where is render function and u r missing $ sign i think $this

Comment: is this your full code? then it's no wonder you don't see anything. you did not construct your class in the visible code.

Comment: You should give information about the MVC framework you're using...

Comment: debug yourself first? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/12772851#12772851

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple issues.

```
var $theTime = date ( "D M j G:i:s T Y");
```

`var` is obsolete which is ironic since you used `public` on the line before it. You should not copy and paste code from other sources.

Also, you cannot call functions when declaring a member variable. You have to set this in your constructor or in a method.

```
this->render('hello');
```

You're missing your `$` for `$this`: `$this->render('hello');`

You also forgot the closing `}` for your class definition.

Lastly, you need to [turn on error reporting so all errors are displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php). PHP wanted to tell you about those errors. Let it.

Comment: Si, and just for argument's sake; OP's got a missing closing brace, but we'll just pretend it was always there to start with ;)

Comment: Quick as always! I added it for the (hopefully) sake of completeness.

Comment: Yeah, you know me in taking *posted* code for *face value* ;) need to cover all the bases, *as it were.*